# Auto updating custom layer parameters while backpropagating in pytorch

Tags: neural-network, gradient, pytorch, backpropagation

I have a pytorch custom layer defined as:

```
class MyCustomLayer(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super(MyCustomLayer, self).__init__()

    self.my_parameter = torch.rand(1, requires_grad = True)

    # the following allows the previously defined parameter to be recognized as a network parameter when instantiating the model
    self.my_registered_parameter = nn.ParameterList([nn.Parameter(self.my_parameter)])

  def forward(self, x):
    return x*self.my_parameter
```

I then define my network where the custom layer is used:

```
class MyNet(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super(MyNet, self).__init__()
    self.layer1 = MyCustomLayer()

  def forward(self, x):
    x = self.layer1(x)
    return x
```

Now Let's instantiate MyNet and observe the issue:

```
# instantiate MyNet and run it over one input value
model = MyNet()
x = torch.tensor(torch.rand(1))
output = model(x)
criterion = nn.MSELoss()
loss = criterion(1, output)
loss.backward()
```

Iterating through model parameters shows `None` for custom layer parameter:

```
for p in model.parameters():
    print (p.grad)

None
```

while directly accessing that parameter shows the correct `grad` value:

```
print(model.layer1.my_parameter.grad)

tensor([-1.4370])
```

This, in turn, prevents the optim step from updating the inner parameters automatically and leaves me with the hassle of having to update those manually. Anyone knows how I can address this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did i.e. `return x*self.my_registered_parameter[0]` worked because you use the registered param for calculating the gradient.

When you call `nn.Parameter` it returns a new object and hence `self.my_parameter` that you use for the operation and the one registered are not same.

You can fix this by declaring the `my_parameter` as `nn.Parameter`

```
self.my_parameter = nn.Parameter(torch.rand(1, requires_grad = True))
self.my_registered_parameter= nn.ParameterList([self.some_parameter])
```

or you don't need to create `my_registered_parameter` variable at all. When you declare `self.my_parameter` as `nn.Parameter` it gets registered as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Alright! 
I had to switch the parameter variable calls within the custom layer to the `nn.ParameterList` object (i.e. `return x*self.my_registered_parameter[0]` instead of x*self.my_parameter ). In this example that meant changing the custom layer's parameter call in forward method to:

```
  def forward(self, x):
    return x*self.my_registered_parameter[0]
```

This is where it would've been nice to have *pass by reference*!

Now optim updates all the parameters as expected!